# What is a project book?

Tags: process, documentation, communication-management

I've been talking with a PM instructor and they said their PM students needed to put together a **project book** as part of their assessment.

I've not heard of this, except referring to all the documentation needed to keep track of a project.  [This template](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/enterprise-solutions/project-book-template-5101) shows headings and indicates the information that should be in it, but otherwise my Google-Fu is failing me.

What I've thought about is that the project book should contain as much information as required by someone taking up the project after the incumbent PM has undergone the [bus scenario.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/how-can-i-prepare-for-getting-hit-by-a-bus)

However, is there anything more detailed / explanatory available?

Comment: See "runbook" or "playbook" for the likely origin of this neologism.

Comment: @downvoter: Any comment on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition we eventually went with was that used by Brooks in chapter 7, **Why Did The Tower of Babel Fail**, of his *The Mythical Man-Month*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the project book needs to be what your teacher thinks it should be.

I've never created a "project book" in all my time working on projects. It is likely a specific term some people use and others do not. So best to ask the teacher some what questions like:

- What is the intended audience?
- What should it contain?
- What is the goal of the document?

Comment: For the record, it's not my teacher. I am the teacher.  And there was another teacher on the same course, but a different session. :-)